# GCM sending message using java

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

Using nodejs and node-gcm I'm sending message to my android client using this code

```
var sender = new gcm.Sender('API KEY');
sender.send(message, regId, function(err, result) {
         if (err) console.log("error");
         else console.log("Message sent! :)");
```

There is something similar on Java? I found this

```
Sender sender = new Sender(GCM_API_KEY);
try {
        Result res = sender.send(message, "token", 3);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But with the Java Sender I can't set the client id. How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no client id needed for sending a GCM message with the Sender class. All you need are the API key and the Registration ID (to be placed where you wrote `"token"`).